# Is In-App Auto renewable subscription's server to server notification notifies when the subscription renewed automatically? (not in sandbox in live)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, swift5, in-app-subscription

I am using In-App Auto renewable subscription and testing in sandbox and also implemented server-to-server notification on my server.

1. I got notification of initial purchase in sandbox, but auto renewal notification(when the subscription is automatically renewing) is not hit on the server. I understood that it is not available in sandbox.

What I want to clarify is, this auto renewal notification is available in live environment? ie, App Store send a notification to our server when the subscription renewing automatically in live environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, renewal events are not arriving via Apple Notifications on both environments. You have to calculate manually your expiration date and schedule validation on your behalf. However there are plenty of ready to go solutions, like our service.

Comment: Thank You.. Then what about the user cancel the auto renewal ? 
If the user cancel auto renewable in settings app, any notification we get from appstore? 
When the DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS hit on our server?